# Drools: rule 2 is not fired, while rule 1 is fired internally (enters in the loop)

Tags: java, drools

I want to fire all rules and exit. In my example I have only 2 rules, but they are interrelated, i.e. rule 2 should be fired after rule 1.
The problem is that it only prints out the output from rule 1. Moreover it looks like it enters into the loop and prints out the same message (`Client is interested in skiing`) internally.

```
package com.sample;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;

/**
 * This is a sample class to launch a rule.
 */
public class TestSimpleRules {

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // load up the knowledge base
            KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
            KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
            KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");

            // go !
            Client client = new Client();
            Season season = new Season();
            client.addProduct("snowboard");
            client.addProduct("ski poles");
            season.setSeason("winter");
            kSession.insert(client);
            kSession.insert(season);
            kSession.fireAllRules();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class Client {

        private Set<String> buyingHistory;
        private String interestedIn;

        public Client()
        {
            buyingHistory = new HashSet<String>();
        }

        public Set<String> getBuyingHistory() {
            return this.buyingHistory;
        }

        public void addProduct(String product) {
            this.buyingHistory.add(product);
        }

        public String getInterestedIn() {
            return this.interestedIn;
        }

        public void setInterestedIn(String interestedI) {
            this.interestedIn = interestedIn;
        }

    }

    public static class Season {

        private String currentSeason;

        public String getSeason() {
            return this.currentSeason;
        }

        public void setSeason(String season) {
            this.currentSeason = season;
        }

    }

}
```

**Rules:**

```
package com.javacodegeeks.drools;

import com.sample.TestSimpleRules.Client;
import com.sample.TestSimpleRules.Season;

rule "Rule #1"
    when
        c : Client( Client.getBuyingHistory() contains "snowboard", thisBuyingHistory : buyingHistory) and
        s: Season( Season.getSeason() == "winter" )
    then
        System.out.println( thisBuyingHistory );
        c.setInterestedIn("skiing");
        System.out.println("Client is interested in skiing");
        update( c );
end

rule "Rule #2"
    when
       c: Client( Client.getInterestedIn() == "skiing" && !(Client.getBuyingHistory() contains "ski jacket"), thisBuyingHistory : buyingHistory) 
    then
       System.out.println("Ski jacket is recommended");
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several technical details first:

1. Do not qualify method calls with class names.
2. To refer to a field, the field name alone is sufficient - no need to call the getter.
3. There's no need to use `and` at the outermost level, it is implied.
4. You can bind a variable to a field and write an assertion for that field in a single construct.
5. Using `modify` to update a fact is preferred.
6. There is an operator `not contains`, so you don't need to write the negated constraint.

(All of the above can be learned from the Drools manual.)

```
rule "Rule #1"
when
    c: Client( buyHist: buyingHistory contains "snowboard" ) 
    s: Season( season == "winter" )
then
    System.out.println( buyHist );
    modify( c ){ setInterestedIn("skiing") }
    System.out.println("Client is interested in skiing");
end

rule "Rule #2"
when
    c: Client( interestedIn == "skiing",
               buyingHistory not contains "ski jacket" ) 
then
    System.out.println("Ski jacket is recommended");
end
```

The loop in firing the first rule is due to the modification of field `interestedIn`, which results in a reevaluation of all rules referring to some `Client` fact. Since there's no constraint in `"Rule #1"` to disqualify it from firing, it fires again. A safe remedy is to constrain the rule to fire only if `interestedIn` isn't equal to `"skiing"`:

```
rule "Rule #1"
when
    c: Client( buyHist: buyingHistory contains "snowboard"
               interestedIn != "skiing" ) 
    s: Season( season == "winter" )
then ... end
```

There are other ways of handling this situation. Rule attribute `no-loop` isn't quite as safe. Check the aforementioned document for other options.